# Getting exception when calling Invoke-Sqlcmd

Tags: powershell

I have the following in a file called Test.sql:

```
SELECT '$(Val1)' AS [Value 1], '$(Val2)' AS [Value 2]
```

I am trying to run the following at the pwershell prompt:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '.\SQLExpress' -Variable @("Val1='Test'","Val2='Test2'") -InputFile ".\SQL\Test.sql"
```

I get the error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Incorrect syntax near ''. At line:1 char:1
>   + Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '.\SQLExpress' -Variable @("Val1='Test'","Val2='Te ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

If I swap out the SQL inside of Test.sql with:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

The powershell command line works and so I think the issue is with the sql file itself.

If I run sqlcmd.exe from a dos prompt providing the equivalent parameters my sql script works.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tries adding the DB name after .\SQLExpress?

Comment: Do you mean using the DATABASE switch?

Comment: I tried with the switch but makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

When I remove the single quotes from the SQL file it all works. Itt seems to work differently from the command prompt sqlcmd.exe.

Comment: Same here! Did you find any explanation about that?

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Was struggling to work out what I did wrong. Not sure why it works differently, the official documentation specifies single quotes for the value which doesn't work...